# syntax error on defining loops in variables (PYTHON)

Tags: python, variables, syntax-error

I'm working on a makeshift algorithm using Python 3.0, i'm still new to programming overall and i'm just working on a personal project.

```
A = for i in range(1):
   print(random.uniform(9, 80))
```

Python told me that it's a syntax error so I just want to know what's the correct syntax on defining variables with loops.

Comment: Where is your code ?

Comment: You can't assign the for loop statement to a variable. You could define a function instead.

Comment: I feel like this may be an xy problem. What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: `A = for i in range(1)` is an invalid statement. You cannot assign a for loop to a variable. Not sure what you were intending to do here.

Comment: I’m voting to close this. It’s a trivial question, and won’t be of benefit to anyone else. OP, Stack Overflow is meant as a reference resource, whereas you probably need a guide or tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign a `for` loop into a variable, instead you just can perform this without the variable:

```
import random

for i in range(1):
   print(random.uniform(9, 80))
```

Answer (score -1):

You would over write the variable if you were looping through something and assigning. You could create A as an empty list, then add each variable in the loop to that list, then print the final list like so:

```
import random
A = []
for i in range(10):
    A.append(random.uniform(9, 87))
print(A)
```

Comment: I’m not sure I understand what _You would over write the variable if you were looping through something and assigning_ has to do with the issue in OP’s code.